why an iframe's section cannot be jumped to?
I have two html files, main.html and iframe.html, and I need to display iframe.html inside main.html as an iframe and main.html is the page I want to stay on:
main.html
<body>
    <a href="iframe.html#goto" target="tableB" class="btn btn-secondary">Find</a>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>         
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Citizen</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- 100 items more -->
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <iframe name="tableB" src="iframe.html" width="100%" height="1000"></iframe>
</body>

iframe.html
<body>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>         
            <tr>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>              
            </tr>  
            <!-- 50 items more -->
            <tr id="goto">
                <td>Alice</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- 50 items more -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

what I want to achieve is, when I click the <a> link, the current page should jump to the the iframe's Alice Smith record, and I don't want to open another page for indexB.html to display, I just want to display it in main.html and do the jump in main.html
But it doesn't work when I click the link button, it doesn't jump to the correct section which is the iframe's Alice Smith record, where did I do wrong?

The container is not scrolling but the iframe is. As a test you can try this.
main.html
<body style="overflow: hidden;">
    <a href="iframe.html#goto" target="tableB" class="btn btn-secondary">Find</a>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>         
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Citizen</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- 100 items more -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
   
    <iframe name="tableB" src="iframe.html" width="100%" height="350px" ></iframe>
   
</body>

iframe.html
<body>
    <table class="table" style="border-spacing:150px">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>         
            <tr>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>              
            </tr> 
            <!-- 50 items more -->
            <tr id="goto">
                <td><h1>Alice</td>
                <td><h1>Smith</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- 50 items more -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>


Thank you but it doesn't work,  Iframe is not even showing
